# Show/Hide Button depending on stored procedure return value

Tags: html, asp.net, stored-procedures, dataset

I'd like to get some help on an issue I'm having. I have a stored procedure that returns a dataset to fill a datagriview. One of the data grid's columns contains 2 manually set buttons, 'View' & 'Add'. These buttons open up a new popup window which displays extra information etc. I would like to be able to hide a 'View' button if 1 of the returned parameter's, POCount, count is equal to 0. i.e. there is nothing to view for that row. What is the best way to make this happen.

My stored procedure is

```
SELECT PM.ProjectCode, 
       PM.ProjectDesc, 
       PM.Active, 
       PM.Chargeable,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM POMaster PO WHERE PO.ProjectCode = PM.ProjectCode) AS POCount

FROM PROJECTMASTER PM
```

Front End Code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="P.O. Number" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" >
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkPONumber" runat="server" Text="View" CssClass="buttonStyle" OnClick="LinkPONumber_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProjectCode") + ";" + Eval("ProjectDesc") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="linkAddPO" runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="buttonStyle" OnClick="LinkAddPO_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProjectCode") + ";" + Eval("ProjectDesc") %>' ></asp:LinkButton> 
</ItemTemplate>                                                                                   
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind

```
        private void BindGrid()
        {
            DSProjectDetails = objProjectMasterBL.GetProjectDetails();
            GvProject.DataSource = DSProjectDetails;
            GvProject.DataBind();
        }


        public DataSet GetProjectDetails()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlProcedureName = "USP_GetProjectListWithPO";
                SqlConnectionObject = DBConnection.InitializeConnection(SqlConnectionObject);

                dsrepeater = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(SqlConnectionObject, CommandType.StoredProcedure, SqlProcedureName);
                return dsrepeater;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Exception in ProjectMasterBL.GetProjectDetails:", ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Apologies if I've sent the wrong sections of code, still residing in the noob ranks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Visible` property of Link Button:-

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="linkAddPO" runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="buttonStyle" 
    OnClick="LinkAddPO_Click" Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("POCount")) == 0 %>'
   CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProjectCode") + ";" + Eval("ProjectDesc") %>'>
 </asp:LinkButton>
```

Whenever your SP returns `POCount` as `0`, you LinkButton will be hidden.